# Can I use a 30 amp disconnect for a 20 amp circuit?

Tags: electrical

I need a 20 amp disconnect for an air to water heat pump.  I can only find 30 and 60 amp disconnects.  Would it be OK to use the 30?

Answer (score 1):

### For the disconnecting means at the equipment, yes

A 30A "air conditioner disconnect" box will work for this job, since it a sufficient current rating for the circuit and switches all ungrounded conductors.  (One theoretically could use a 20A two-pole/DPST lightswitch for this, even, but that's likely to be more expensive than a 30A A/C disconnect box.)

Comment: The 30-Amp disconnect would be the item selected for this job.  Typically we use fusible disconnects for better protection of the motorized equipment.  Simply install 20-Amp fuses in place of the 30.

Answer (score 0):

When it says 30 amps it means it can go up to 30 amps. If it is a fused disconnect it will hold up to 30 amp fuses. If it has fuses just use 20 amp fuses, they will work as they are supposed to. Size the wires appropriately, usually 12 gauge for a 20 amp circuit and use a 20 amp circuit breaker. If you already had larger wire and a larger breaker you should use 20 amp fuses in a fused disconnect to protect the equipment. The breaker will protect the wire.